# GMP faulty naive primality algorithm c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, rsa, primes, gmp

I implemented the following GMP function for an RSA program. Basically, the program generates random `mpz*t` numbers until one of them returns `true` for this function.

```
bool isPrime(const mpz_t bignum)
{
    mpz_t modnum; mpz_init(modnum);
    if(mpz_cmp_ui(bignum,4)<0 && mpz_cmp_si(bignum,0)>=0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Trivially prime.\n");
        return false;
    }
    else if(mpz_mod_ui(modnum,bignum,2)==0)
        return false;
    mpz_clear(modnum);

    mpz_t i,rootnum; 
    mpz_inits(i,modnum,rootnum,NULL);
    mpz_sqrt(rootnum,bignum);
    mpz_set_str(i,"3",10);

    for(;mpz_cmp(rootnum,i)>0; mpz_add_ui(i,i,2)) {
        mpz_mod(modnum,bignum,i);
        if(mpz_cmp(modnum,i)==0)
            return false;
    }
    mpz_clears(modnum,i,rootnum,NULL);
    return true;
}
```

Here is the function that calls `isPrime()` as a subroutine:

```
void generate_pq(mpz_t& p, mpz_t& q) 
{
    gmp_randstate_t rstate;
    gmp_randinit_default(rstate);
    gmp_randseed_ui(rstate,time(NULL));

    printf("\nGenerating keys...\n");
    do {
        mpz_urandomb(p,rstate,32);
    } while(!isPrime(p));
    printf("\n***** p *****\n");
    gmp_printf("    %Zd\n",p);
    do {
        mpz_urandomb(q,rstate,32);
    } while(!isPrime(q));
    gmp_randclear(rstate);

    printf("\n***** q *****\n");
    gmp_printf("    %Zd\n",q);
}
```

The program compiles and runs no problem. However, the numbers generated are not prime and yet `isPrime()` still returns true for them. Could anyone point out the flaw in the algorithm of my primality test? Here is the regular `int` version of my `isPrime()` function, if you'd like to compare:

```
bool isPrime(uint64_t n) 
{
    //waste of time
    if(n < 4) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Trivially prime.\n");
        return true;
    }
    //even #, not prime
    else if(n%2==0) {
        return false;
    }
    //check if divisible by all odd #s < sqrt(n)
    for(uint64_t i=3; i<(uint64_t)sqrt(n+1); i+=2) {
        if(n%i==0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you give example number with invalid output?

Comment: Found the problem. But here you go: p = 1977882773, q = 1932673697

Comment: Do you know about the mpz_nextprime function in gmplib? Choose a random number of the size you want, then call mpz_nextprime to get the next larger prime number. Gmplib also has random-number generators if you want to use them.

Comment: That's something I didn't confirm with a prof. Not a math major. So I only need to check with all prime numbers? For the latter statement, I am generating random numbers using GMP.

Comment: I double checked `mpz_nextprime()`, for this particular instance, I have to use the naive primality test. The function you're referring to uses probabilistic primality.

Comment: Most RSA implementations use the probabilistic methods. It's too computationally expensive to prove such a large number prime, and not necessary. For numbers the size of your p and q, instead of trial division to the square root it would be much faster to use a pocklington test of primality.

Comment: Totally agree. My algorithms prof has us using naive primality testing to prove a point about time complexity. I have another version of this RSA program that uses `gmp_probab_prim()`.

Comment: It's O(sqrt(n)). What point is he trying to prove? Show him the Pocklington test. It proves primality, absolutely, and is very much faster than trial division.

Comment: We had to do a few iterations of the RSA program using different methods. 1 program with uint64_t, another using GMP and probabilistic primality testing, and a 3rd using GMP and naive primality testing. I couldn't tell you his motivations >__<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in my for-loop.

```
for(;mpz_cmp(rootnum,i)>0; mpz_add_ui(i,i,2)) {
    mpz_mod(modnum,bignum,i);
    if(mpz_cmp(modnum,i)==0) // <-----not supposed to do if(modnum==i)
        return false;
```

The correct version of this for-loop is here:

```
for(;mpz_cmp(rootnum,i)>0; mpz_add_ui(i,i,2)) {
    mpz_mod(modnum,bignum,i);
    if(mpz_cmp_ui(modnum,0)==0) // <-- if bignum % modnum == 0, return false
        return false;
```